# Can i save a list as template using PnP script inside my modern communication site

Tags: administration, pnp, online, communication-site, modern

I am working on a communication modern SharePoint site. and seems these modern sites, do not allow us to save the list as template. as i want to save our list as template and re-create it inside another site. so can anyone advice if there is a PnP script to do this task without having to allow custom script on the modern site or enable any feature?. as i do not want to modify the source site, either by enabling any features or allowing custom scripts.

Thanks

Comment: check this, https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/09/sharepoint-online-create-list-template-using-powershell.html but its not using pnp

Comment: @KarthikJaganathan this will not work inside modern communication sites.

Answer (score 3):

The best recommended approach is use the PnP Provisioning template.

- Download the PnP Provisioning template using PnP
- Filter the downloaded template (xml) because there is no way to generate only the specific list template, by default it will download all lists/libraries from the specific site.
- Then create a new list using the filtered PnP template.

**Sample code to get specif list from SharePoint Online for PnP Provisioning template:**

```
$listName = "List Title for which want to generate template";
$outputTemplateFileName = "C:\Temp\PnP\SPListPnPProvisioning\ListTemplateDownloaded.xml";
$templates = Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -OutputInstance -Handlers Lists
$singleListTemplate = $templates.Lists | Where-Object { $_.Title -eq $listName }
$templates.Lists.Clear()
$templates.Lists.Add($singleListTemplate)
Save-PnPProvisioningTemplate -InputInstance $templates -Out $outputTemplateFileName;

Write-host "Successfully PnP list template has been customized for a single list."
```

**How to create a new list in the target site using the downloaded PnP template:**

```
CLS
$userName = "Global-sharepoint2019@globalsharepoint2019.onmicrosoft.com"
$passWord = "YourSPOPassword"
$encPassWord = convertto-securestring -String $passWord -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $encPassWord

Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://globalsharepoint2019.sharepoint.com/sites/SharePointRNDClassic" -Credentials $cred

Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path "C:\Temp\PnP\SPListPnPProvisioning\ListTemplate.xml"

Write-host "Successfully a list has been created in SharePoint online."
```

Demo Example:

[image: Create list using PnP Provisioning template]

**Please read the below article where step by step it is explained how to do with the video demo:**

[Create SharePoint online list using PnP provisioning template](https://global-sharepoint.com/pnp-powershell/create-sharepoint-online-list-using-pnp-provisioning-template/)

Comment: You can specify which list(s) to include... see my answer above :-)

Comment: @SP Expert i tried the `Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Handlers Lists -ListsToExtract <GUID or Title> -Out .\template.xml` and `Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path .\template.xml`..but on the second command i got this exception `Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate : Referenced content type 0x01***58 not available in site or in template` now our list contain a custom content type, so could this be the reason?

Comment: @SharePointTestDev - In my demo I have not used ListsToExtract <GUID or Title> parameter, I have used -Handlers Lists, this will give everything all lists, libraries and content types etc...using the demo approach we can filter this to fit our specific requirement....try to exclude the  ListsToExtract <GUID or Title> parameter and see the result - how it works. :-)

Comment: @RuneSperre - Thanks for letting us know about the -ListsToExtract <GUID or Title> parameter, when I have explored about this it was not known to me, however, still I am not sure how does it work - I think it gives .pnp file rather the xml file as per the below MSDN command: Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out template.pnp -ListsToExtract "Title of List One","95c4efd6-08f4-4c67-94ae-49d696ba1298","Title of List Three"

Comment: It will output xml - they have just used .pnp as the extension for some strange reason :)

Comment: @RuneSperre oohk, thanks mate :-)

Comment: @SPExpert so will your script extract the list fields as well? as you did not specify so in the -Handler?

Comment: @SPExpert second question, how i will include this list template in the destination site? using the UI? or Pnp?

Comment: @SharePointTestDev - Handler List , will include all fields as well. To create in target site you need to use the PnP, answer updated, please refer the "How to create a new list in the target site using the downloaded PnP template:" section :-) for details, refer the demo video mentioned the reference URL.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpprovisioningtemplate?view=sharepoint-ps) to export a list as a template and then recreate the list on another site using [Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/apply-pnpprovisioningtemplate?view=sharepoint-ps).

To export just a specific list you would use the following syntax:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/comsite
Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Handlers Lists -ListsToExtract <GUID or Title> -Out .\template.xml
```

To include fields and content types, modify -Handlers to:

```
-Handlers Lists, Fields, ContentTypes
```

The file `template.xml` can then be applied to another site using:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/anothersite
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path .\template.xml
```

Comment: so the -out and -path will be a location inside my PC?

Comment: Correct. In my example i used .\filename.xml which would be the current directory

Comment: and will this command by any mean affect the source list? i do not think so? is this correct?

Comment: i tried your appraoch , but on the Apply i for this expectation `Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate : Referenced content type 0x01***58 not available in site or in template` now our list contain a custom content type, so could this be the reason?

Comment: It will not modify the source at all. To include handlers, you will need to include that as well in the handlers parameter. I will update the answer on how to do that.

Comment: ok thanks i modify the handler, but now i will get this exception `Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate : The 'value' argument cannot be null.`

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the PnP module?

Comment: i am using this version 3.14.1910.0

Comment: i update it to version `3.18.2002.0` but still the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104755/discussion-between-rune-sperre-and-sharepoint-testdev).

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to consider using a Site Design for this, especially if you want it to be repeatable easily - and to let site owners manage things themselves.  You can use a Site Design at site provisioning time or at a later point to instantiate specific artifacts, like Content Types, lists/libraries, etc.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview